# Getting auth code from URL after redirection

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to work with Dropbox API, but before everything I want to do authorization.By following Dropbox API Docs, I have to redirect user to specific URL, after that user has to trust my app, and then after confirmation user will be redirected back to my app with authorization code in URL.I need that authorization code for making requests to endpoints.

I'm using VueJS 2, so I created auth.js file where I will store all related data, so far it looks like this

```
export default {

    authorize(authCode) {
        authCode = authCode || this.getAuthCode()

        if(!authCode) {
            window.location.replace(`https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${config.APP_KEY}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${config.REDIRECT_URI}`)
            const code = this.stripAuthCode(window.location.href)
            this.setAuthCode(code)
        }
    },

    stripAuthCode(url) {
        return url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1, url-length - 2)
    },

    getAuthCode() {
        return localStorage.getItem('auth-code')
    },

    setAuthCode(authCode) {
        localStorage.setItem('auth-code', authCode)
    }

}
```

So the idea is store the code from URL into the localStorage as `auth-code` key, and later on I can use it for making requests to Dropbox endpoints, and getting the auth token.

For testing purposes I'm importing that file in my root component `App.vue` and trigerring the authorize method into the `mounted()` hook (I'll move that later on in better place, so far so good).

```
import auth from './services/Auth'

export default {
    ...
    mounted() {
        auth.authorize()
    }
}
```

PROBLEM: It's looks like everything goes fine, but for some reasons the `auth-code` into the localStorage is set to `http://localhost:8080` even the URL in adress bar looks like this `http://localhost:8080/?code=<auth_code>#/`

> Note: `stripAuthCode` method get the auth code in way that it takes
>   everything after the `=` and remove last 2 characters which is
>   hashbang generated by Vue and slash.

Thanks.